# Open and plot a large raster with Python xarray

Tags: python, rasterio, esri-ascii-raster, xarray, rioxarray

I have an ASCII Esri file of the type:

```
ncols 5201
nrows 4001
xllcorner -65
yllcorner -35
cellsize 0.025
NODATA_value -9999
-9999 -9999 -9999 255 256 -9999 -9999 ...
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 ...
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 255 -9999 230 ...
...
```

I'm trying to import it with `rioxarray` by doing:

```py
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray

da = rioxarray.open_rasterio('data.asc',masked=True)
da.plot()
```

What I get is a graph with the correct coordinates, but no data shown:
[image]

Do you know why this is?

`da` is imported as an `xarray.DataArray` and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Seems like it is a lot of data to plot. Can you try with `da.plot.imshow()`?

Comment: I get `ValueError: A 3-dimensional array was passed to imshow(), but there is no dimension that could be color.  At least one dimension must be of size 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA), and not given as x or y`. I guess because the array has also the "band" dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import rioxarray

da = rioxarray.open_rasterio('data.asc', masked=True)
da.squeeze().plot.imshow()
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the data were just too many and the `xarray` plot function could not handle it. By selecting a chunk of size not much smaller than the original data, the plot looks fine.

Note that by using `rasterio`'s `show` function instead there is no problem plotting this amount of data:

```py
from rasterio.plot import show
show(rasterio.open('data.asc'))
```

[image]