# RuntimeWarning when I try to plot a raster

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rioxarray

I'm using JupyterNotebook to analyze some GIS data. I need to clip a raster and plot the result but I've a strange problem. Folder with data is [here](https://github.com/MaxDragonheart/PyGIS-Blog/tree/post_%2312/sample_data/photovoltaic_potential_analysis); the raster size is 1MB.

I'm be able to plot the source raster without problem:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray as rxr
from xarray.plot import imshow

vector = gpd.read_file(buildings)
raster = rxr.open_rasterio(dsm).squeeze()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

imshow(
    raster,
    cmap='Blues',
    ax=ax,
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I clip the raster with a GeoDataframe with a hundred polygons.

```py
raster_clipped = raster.rio.clip(
    geometries=vector.geometry, crs=raster.rio.crs, all_touched=True, drop=True
)
```

Below the output:
[image]

With the code below I save the output so I can see it also with QGIS:

```py
raster_clipped.rio.to_raster('clip.tif', driver="GTiff")
```

[image]
The problem comes when I try to plot the clipped raster inside a JupyterNotebook:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

imshow(
    raster_clipped,
    cmap='Blues',
    ax=ax,
)
plt.show()
```

I see the image below:
[image]
And this error:

> /home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/pygis_blog-Mlm5bQxV-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:480: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in subtract
> vrange -= a_min

It seems I can see only the nodata values:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
raster_clipped.plot.hist(color="blue", bins=10)
ax.set_title("Highs distribution")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open and plot a large raster with Python xarray](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384577/open-and-plot-a-large-raster-with-python-xarray)

Comment: I've already tested this solution but it is not usefull for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Opening in masked mode

rioxarray.open_rasterio(dsm, masked=True)

Option 2: plot with robust=True

https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html#robust